# json_decode in php retruns null

Tags: php, json, decode

i am trying to parse json its working in online website but not working on json_decode() php, below is my json.

```
{"category":"group_channel:message_send","sender":{"nickname":"Four Six","user_id":"917777770046","profile_url":"https:\/\/sendbird.com\/main\/img\/profiles\/profile_05_512px.png","metadata":{}},"custom_type":"application\/octet-stream","mention_type":"users","mentioned_users":[],"app_id":"C14BC2EA-ED60-4A82-9441-5C312A6EA991","members":[{"is_blocking_sender":false,"unread_message_count":1,"total_unread_message_count":1,"is_active":true,"is_online":true,"is_hidden":0,"channel_mention_count":0,"nickname":"Four Six","is_blocked_by_sender":false,"user_id":"917777770046","channel_unread_message_count":0,"state":"joined","push_enabled":true,"push_trigger_option":true,"profile_url":"https:\/\/sendbird.com\/main\/img\/profiles\/profile_05_512px.png","metadata":{}}],"type":"MESG","payload":{"custom_type":"application\/octet-stream","created_at":1570690168039,"translations":{},"message":"H4sIAAAAAAAAALWTXYucMBSG\/4rkWockRh3nrrNlYViYFpbSyyUmx5mwmkiMpXaZ\/94T54MpC6Ut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\n","data":"message_form","message_id":2839079954},"channel":{"is_distinct":false,"name":"KPGI Workday","custom_type":"kpgi_workday_data","is_ephemeral":false,"channel_url":"sendbird_group_channel_150279781_505f37b8b653c01febe37245d447f7098d0fe53c","is_public":false,"is_super":false,"data":"{\"chatApp\":\"sendbird\",\"chatId\":\"4e2005f7-d5b5-4c69-acb4-5fd12bc42cba\",\"topParentId\":\"4e2005f7-d5b5-4c69-acb4-5fd12bc42cba\",\"formNumber\":\"0\",\"creatorName\":\"Four Six\",\"creatorId\":\"917777770046\",\"topic\":\"KPGI Workday\",\"formstatus\":\"{\\\"kpgi_workday_travel_form\\\":0,\\\"kpgi_workday_initiate_break\\\":0,\\\"kpgi_workday_travel\\\":0,\\\"kpgi_workday_expense\\\":0,\\\"kpgi_workday_close_data\\\":0,\\\"kpgi_workday_timesheet\\\":0}\",\"type\":\"kpgi_workday_data\",\"parentId\":\"\"}","is_discoverable":false},"sdk":"Android"}
```

Comment: The JSON you've posted here looks as though it is invalid - check with something like jsonlint.com

Comment: [`json_last_error`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) and [`json_last_error_msg`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php).

Comment: The issue is this `"data":"{\"chatApp\":\"sendbird\",\"chatId\":\"4e2005f7-d5b5-4c69-acb4-5fd12bc42cba\",\"topParentId\":\"4e2005f7-d5b5-4c69-acb4-5fd12bc42cba\",\"formNumber\":\"0\",\"creatorName\":\"Four Six\",\"creatorId\":\"917777770046\",\"topic\":\"KPGI Workday\",\"formstatus\":\"{\\\"kpgi_workday_travel_form\\\":0,\\\"kpgi_workday_initiate_break\\\":0,\\\"kpgi_workday_travel\\\":0,\\\"kpgi_workday_expense\\\":0,\\\"kpgi_workday_close_data\\\":0,\\\"kpgi_workday_timesheet\\\":0}\",\"type\":\"kpgi_workday_data\",\"parentId\":\"\"}",`

Comment: This is simply invalid json, you need to fix it at the source. Where do you get it from?

Comment: Someones edit changed the JSONString so that is would no longer validate with jsonlint, so I have rolled it back to the version originally posted by the questioner and now it **does validate** with jsonlint as it originally did

Answer (score 0):

Please try this JSON:

> {"category":"group_channel:message_send","sender":{"nickname":"Four Six","user_id":"917777770046","profile_url":"https://sendbird.com/main/img/profiles/profile_05_512px.png","metadata":{}},"custom_type":"application/octet-stream","mention_type":"users","mentioned_users":[],"app_id":"C14BC2EA-ED60-4A82-9441-5C312A6EA991","members":[{"is_blocking_sender":false,"unread_message_count":1,"total_unread_message_count":1,"is_active":true,"is_online":true,"is_hidden":0,"channel_mention_count":0,"nickname":"Four Six","is_blocked_by_sender":false,"user_id":"917777770046","channel_unread_message_count":0,"state":"joined","push_enabled":true,"push_trigger_option":true,"profile_url":"https://sendbird.com/main/img/profiles/profile_05_512px.png","metadata":{}}],"type":"MESG","payload":{"custom_type":"application/octet-stream","created_at":1570690168039,"translations":{},"message":"H4sIAAAAAAAAALWTXYucMBSG/4rkWockRh3nrrNlYViYFpbSyyUmx5mwmkiMpXaZ/94T54MpC6Ut\nVASPb3Ke85W8kR7GUR5gp8mGCOCUFm2V6aIpMqHKOpOqEVnRasYbJbhqZFbqNeNFVWdlK1QmqoZm\nUqO+VrpSDLgStCApab3rEVmzankoFSWqYR4A1UvQl9b5HlV1lOGPE8D9g5w7J9HhjSyEy/eMoAx3\njAEGsmEpAW0CWNl0Mew++nYyPC5ORFrtndEofgM/GmdRi87KWfQJEYu0FYuGlkHGb+8a08F+6hvw\n78trjR/DXvYx2KObPEqdvCnP5jsK0EvT4R+aUmuPnUDuKSUHsHphLunLMI1nGyPDp3ZrfDiehcG7\nFnP4bFSYPHzxF1g/72zroo2w3mnTGtDb+X2S17UPWCErKlrWlDG65hX6xXr5fb0xOiI4ZXXGKL7/\nSl9f6Pk9/dYA8pTltUiTbefUa/KUJs9H+Tr5YfLJg+ucne+UNPkI3dGkCXJpjk47q41cWo0x+XpV\n1oyWeY6CPZBNVa2YKHLBKpysCTHlvcNmJl9hDGfUMvPJBh8Xr7Q4g1j6dccPM8TzscRclj1AeLGX\n0V6Tu2/PLy2oc178rnOn6Pif7qIZH1w/dBAgkmfy9xMsebpcsdvBZ5jw6SfcNiZDPgQAAA==\n","data":"message_form","message_id":2839079954},"channel":{"is_distinct":false,"name":"KPGI Workday","custom_type":"kpgi_workday_data","is_ephemeral":false,"channel_url":"sendbird_group_channel_150279781_505f37b8b653c01febe37245d447f7098d0fe53c","is_public":false,"is_super":false,"data":"{\"chatApp\":\"sendbird\",\"chatId\":\"4e2005f7-d5b5-4c69-acb4-5fd12bc42cba\",\"topParentId\":\"4e2005f7-d5b5-4c69-acb4-5fd12bc42cba\",\"formNumber\":\"0\",\"creatorName\":\"Four Six\",\"creatorId\":\"917777770046\",\"topic\":\"KPGI Workday\",\"formstatus\":\"{\"kpgi_workday_travel_form\":0,\"kpgi_workday_initiate_break\":0,\"kpgi_workday_travel\":0,\"kpgi_workday_expense\":0,\"kpgi_workday_close_data\":0,\"kpgi_workday_timesheet\":0}\",\"type\":\"kpgi_workday_data\",\"parentId\":\"\"}","is_discoverable":false},"sdk":"Android"}

I have made some edits. If this works, you can do a string compare to see the differences, but overall, I just deleted some extra slashes.